# missing syslinux.cfg file for ubuntu 16.04 iso installation on USB

Tags: live-usb, 16.04, syslinux

After using installing `ubuntu-16.04-server-amd64.iso` on to a USB stick (using  [lili](http://www.linuxliveusb.com)), I get the "boot:" console because the syslinux.cfg file is empty, as [explained here](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/error-could-not-find-kernel-image-linux/).

Where can I find an example of the syslinux.cfg file for ubuntu 16.04?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to successfully install the iso on my USB using the [Pen Drive Linux](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/) installer.

Answer (score 0):

I've got same problem, recreated install USB flash drive and tried again. Here is the correct text. Copy and paste inside syslinux (cfg file without any extension) all of that below:

```
default menu.c32
prompt 0
menu title UNetbootin
timeout 100

label unetbootindefault
menu label Default
kernel /ubnkern
append initrd=/ubninit file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed boot=casper quiet splash ---

label ubnentry0
menu label ^Help
kernel /ubnkern
append initrd=/ubninit 

label ubnentry1
menu label ^Try Ubuntu without installing
kernel /casper/vmlinuz.efi
append initrd=/casper/initrd.lz file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed boot=casper  quiet splash ---

label ubnentry2
menu label ^Install Ubuntu
kernel /casper/vmlinuz.efi
append initrd=/casper/initrd.lz file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed boot=casper only-ubiquity  quiet splash ---

label ubnentry3
menu label ^Check disc for defects
kernel /casper/vmlinuz.efi
append initrd=/casper/initrd.lz boot=casper integrity-check  quiet splash ---

label ubnentry4
menu label Test ^memory
kernel /install/mt86plus
append initrd=/ubninit 

label ubnentry5
menu label ^Boot from first hard disk
kernel /ubnkern
append initrd=/ubninit 

label ubnentry6
menu label Try Ubuntu without installing
kernel /casper/vmlinuz.efi
append initrd=/casper/initrd.lz file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed boot=casper quiet splash ---

label ubnentry7
menu label Install Ubuntu
kernel /casper/vmlinuz.efi
append initrd=/casper/initrd.lz file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed boot=casper only-ubiquity quiet splash ---

label ubnentry8
menu label OEM install (for manufacturers)
kernel /casper/vmlinuz.efi
append initrd=/casper/initrd.lz file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed boot=casper only-ubiquity quiet splash oem-config/enable=true ---

label ubnentry9
menu label Check disc for defects
kernel /casper/vmlinuz.efi
append initrd=/casper/initrd.lz boot=casper integrity-check quiet splash ---
```

If you do not have any cfg-file, just copy it from any Ubuntu install media. Open with Wordpad and paste into it the text. Cfg-file must be in media root (for example K:/, where K -- is your USB flash letter) folder. It is strongly recommended to have at least 2 bootable Ubuntu media.

Answer (score -1):

I'm sure you found it by now but, copy and paste this into the "UUI" folder where it resides:

```
# This file was automatically populated by Universal USB Installer - http://www.pendrivelinux.com
prompt 0
DEFAULT append

LABEL append
CONFIG /isolinux/isolinux.cfg
APPEND /isolinux
```